# How to insert rows in delta table according to conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, delta-lake

i have a delta table:

```
    id  vehicle production  asIs    EU    EU_variant    status  
   1    A3345               PQ1298  FV1   FV1_variant   OK  
   2    A3346   B3346       PQ1287  FV2   FV2_variant   NOT_OK
   3    A3346   B3346       PQ1207  FV2   FV2_variant   NOT_OK
   4            A3347               QP9   QP9_variant   OK  
   5            A3347               QP9   QP9_variant   NOT_OK
   6            A3347               QP3   QP3_variant   OK  
   7            A3348       MP6553  YR34  YR34_variant  NOT_OK  
   8            A3348       MP6554  YR35  YR35_variant  NOT_OK  
   9            A3348       MP6554  YR35  YR35_variant  NOT_OK
```

i want to insert one more row where it should check if the same vehicle is already present and if its status is NOT_OK then dont insert else insert the row.
if vehicle value is not present check for production  number and status.

for ex: if i want to insert row

```
1    A3345       null      PQ1298  FV1   FV1_variant   OK
```

since A3345 is already present but status is OK, so it will insert another row

```
    id  vehicle production  asIs    EU    EU_variant    status  
   1    A3345               PQ1298  FV1   FV1_variant   OK  
   1    A3345               PQ1298  FV1   FV1_variant   OK
   2    A3346   B3346       PQ1287  FV2   FV2_variant   NOT_OK
   3    A3346   B3346       PQ1207  FV2   FV2_variant   NOT_OK
   4            A3347               QP9   QP9_variant   OK  
   5            A3347               QP9   QP9_variant   NOT_OK
   6            A3347               QP3   QP3_variant   OK  
   7            A3348       MP6553  YR34  YR34_variant  NOT_OK  
   8            A3348       MP6554  YR35  YR35_variant  NOT_OK  
   9            A3348       MP6554  YR35  YR35_variant  NOT_OK
```

ex2:
if i want to insert :`2    A3346   B3346       PQ1287  FV2   FV2_variant   NOT_OK`
since A3346 is already present and status is NOT_OK , it wont insert the row

ex3:
if i want to insert row : `9   null       A3348       MP6554  YR35  YR35_variant  NOT_OK`
since vehicle is null it will check for production, since production is already present and status is NOT_OK it wont insert.

how to achieve this using pyspark delta table

Comment: have you looked onto merge command? I think that it should be possible to express that logic

Comment: @samkart can you help me with this